# Element androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout is not allowed here Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android data binding and android studio. I have below xml file.

I am facing issue.

Element `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` is not allowed here

I tried changing CordinatorLayout with MaterialCardView and it shows the again

Element `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` is not allowed here

I am not able to understand what is the issue here. But when i build the project it build successfully.
But android studio doesn't show auto complete. Anybody have any idea please.

```
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#AF5C5C"
        android:padding="25dp"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity">
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/wrapper_card"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_show_signup"
                    android:id="@+id/button_show_signin"
                    android:text="Signin"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_show_signin"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button_show_signup"
                    android:text="SignUP"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_show_signin"
                    android:hint="@string/user_name"
                    android:id="@+id/user_name_container"
                    style="@style/AppTextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        style="@style/AppTextInputEditText"
                        android:id="@+id/user_edit_text"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_container"
                    android:hint="@string/mobile"
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_number_container"
                    style="@style/AppTextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/mobile_number"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        style="@style/AppTextInputEditText"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mobile_number_container"
                    android:hint="@string/address"
                    android:id="@+id/password_container"
                    style="@style/AppTextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        style="@style/AppTextInputEditText"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_image"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/view"
            android:tint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happened to me a few times, so i hope this works for you too:

Option 1:
File > invalidate caches and restart > invalidate cache and restart 
then gradle sync you project ( disable gradle offline mode if it's on)

Option 2:
Delete .idea folder from your project close the project and reopen to have Android studio 
regenerate new .idea Sync your project

Comment: This fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar issue and I realized that my layout file was in res > values rather than res > layout.

So after moving the file over to the right folder, it resolved the issue.

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]